# How to index and search nested documents/structured data in Lucene or similar libraries?

Tags: java, json, lucene

I have a structured JSON data in the following form:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "hand",
    "quantity": 2,
    "digits": [
        {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "thumb",
            "quantity": 1,
            "components": [
                {
                    "id": 44,
                    "name": "thumb",
                    "position": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 45,
            "name": "fingers",
            "quantity": 4,
            "components": [
                {
                    "id": 46,
                    "name": "index",
                    "position": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 47,
                    "name": "middle",
                    "position": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 48,
                    "name": "ring",
                    "position": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 49,
                    "name": "little",
                    "position": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to index these data, using Java, so that it would be possible afterwards to make queries to get the needed information.

To that end a solution could be using [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) which supports nested documents since version 3.4. However, I could not find any tutorial nor a simple example on how a nested document can be created.

Can anyone explain how to create a Lucene document for structured data?

Alternatively, are there other libraries similar to Lucene which better support indexing and searching of structured data?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question?? I am having the same problem but with xml nested documents. Please guide me to a tutorial or something if you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution in your case is to use path enumerations ("Dewey Decimal"). For example, yor first three tems would be "42", "42.43", and "42.43.44", while your fourth item would be "42.45". Make sure your slots are large enough for the largest number of items you will need -- for example, "042.043.044".